# Include a php variable in json schema data - wordpress site - invalid json error

Tags: php, json, wordpress, variables, schema

```
    <script type="application/ld+json">
{
  "@context": "http://schema.org",
  "@type": "LocalBusiness",
  "name": "storename",
  "image": "https://staticqa.store.com/wp-content/themes/faf/images/store-logo.png",
  "@id": '.json_encode($storeid)'.,
  "url": "",
  "telephone": '.json_encode($storephone).',
  "priceRange": "$1-$20",
  "address": {
    "@type": "PostalAddress",
    "streetAddress": '.json_encode($storestreetaddress).',
    "addressLocality": '.json_encode($storecityaddress).',
    "postalCode": '.json_encode($storepostaladdress).',
    "addressCountry": "USA"
  },
  "geo": {
    "@type": "GeoCoordinates",
    "latitude": '.json_encode($storelatitude).',
    "longitude": '.json_encode($storelongitude).'
  },
  "openingHoursSpecification": [{
    "@type": "OpeningHoursSpecification",
    "dayOfWeek": "Monday",
    "opens": '.json_encode($storehoursmondaythursday).',
    "closes": ""
  },{
    "@type": "OpeningHoursSpecification",
    "dayOfWeek": "Friday",
    "opens": '.json_encode($storehoursfriday).',
    "closes": ""
  },{
    "@type": "OpeningHoursSpecification",
    "dayOfWeek": "Saturday",
    "opens": '.json_encode($storehourssat).',
    "closes": ""
  },{
    "@type": "OpeningHoursSpecification",
    "dayOfWeek": "Sunday",
    "opens": '.json_encode($storehourssun).',
    "closes": ""
  },{
    "@type": "OpeningHoursSpecification",
    "dayOfWeek": "Tuesday",
    "opens": '.json_encode($storehoursmondaythursday).',
    "closes": ""
  },{
    "@type": "OpeningHoursSpecification",
    "dayOfWeek": "Wednesday",
    "opens": '.json_encode($storehoursmondaythursday).',
    "closes": ""
  },{
    "@type": "OpeningHoursSpecification",
    "dayOfWeek": "Thursday",
    "opens": '.json_encode($storehoursmondaythursday).',
    "closes": ""
  }],
  "sameAs": '.json_encode($fblink).'
}
</script>
```

I have this section of schema data in my php wordpress file. I am getting the variables from my post and then I am trying to insert the variables into my schema data. This is a template page so I need it to be dynamic. I am getting a warning in my console when I run this page though that says this is invalid json code. Any idea what could be wrong?

Comment: According to the state machine diagram on the JSON website, only escaped double-quote characters are allowed, not single-quotes. Hence you need to replace single quote by double quotes.

Comment: I just tried this and it did not solve the problem. I'm still getting a malformed JSON error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

configure array in php and after `json_encode` for example

```
$meta = [
  "@context" => "http://schema.org",
  "@type" => "LocalBusiness",
  "name" => "storename",
  "image" => "https://staticqa.store.com/wp-content/themes/faf/images/store-logo.png",
  "@id" => $storeid,
  "url" => "",
  "telephone" => $storephone,
  .... etc
]
```

and in template

```
<script>
    <?php echo json_encode($meta) ?>
</script>
```

Comment: This worked! I didn't do it by making an array but I changed out each value in the json to be <?php echo json_encode($variableName) ?> and that fixed it. Thank you.

Comment: @pongahead better configure array and `json_encode` because you can't be sure what json correct

Answer (score 0):

You can put it all in php echo and use variables:

```
    echo '
<script type="application/ld+json">
{
  "@context": "http://schema.org/",
  "@type": "Product",
  "name": "'. the_title() .'",
  "image": [
    "https://example.com/photos/1x1/photo.jpg",
    "https://example.com/photos/4x3/photo.jpg",
    "https://example.com/photos/16x9/photo.jpg"
   ],
  "brand": {
    "@type": "Thing",
    "name": "ACME"
  },
  "aggregateRating": {
    "@type": "AggregateRating",
    "ratingValue": "4.4",
    "ratingCount": "89"
  },
  "offers": {
    "@type": "AggregateOffer",
    "lowPrice": "119.99",
    "highPrice": "199.99",
    "priceCurrency": "USD"
  }
}
</script>
';
```